# The table mysql.proc is missing, corrupt, or contains bad data

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I'm getting the following error message when trying to call a stored procedure:

```
The table mysql.proc is missing, corrupt, or contains bad data
```

I've tried performing CHECK and REPAIR on the table, but it's not made any difference.

How can I fix the issue and get stored procedures back again?

Comment: Questions: 1) What version of MSQL are you using ? 2) Did you perform a recent upgrade ? 3) Did you import MySQL data from an older version of MySQL ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while back, and `mysql_upgrade` etc refused to fix it.

In the end I simply took the table structure from a 'good' database and compared it to the 'broken' one. Then made the necessary adjustments. In my case I found that one column had changed slightly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've run `show create table mysql.proc` on a working and non-working server (same MySQL version) and the result is identical on both.

Comment: @Eborbob - which versions?  What was the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: 1. Version ? 2 . When table got corrupted ? 3. Was it there earlier 4. What changes have you done . Please provide more information